# What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple compression program in Python, but am receiving this error

```
with open("admin.dll", "r").read() as text:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Why am I getting this error? This is my full code

```
import zlib, sys, time, base64
with open("admin.txt", "r").read() as file:
    print("Uncompressed: " + str(sys.getsizeof(file)))
    compressed = zlib.compress(file, 9)
    print("Compressed: ", end="")
    print(sys.getsizeof(compressed))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking Python to treat the result of the expression `open("admin.dll", "r").read()` (a string) as a context manager. Context managers are expected to have a `__exit__` method, but strings don't have those methods.

You'd normally pass in the *file object*:

```
with open("admin.dll", "r") as fileobj:
    text = fileobj.read()
```

File objects *do* have the required context manager methods.

Note that you have other errors too; `sys.getsizeof` produces the memory size of a Python object, *not* the size of a file. You could use [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) for that, or seek to the end of the file and use `fileobj.tell()` to get a size. To get the size of the compressed result, use `len()`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should open the file. Appoint a variable to it. In your case file.
Then on the next line you can read the file by calling f.read()